# magnific popup group do not working

Tags: magnific-popup

I'm using the [following tool](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/) for my gallery and I've created the following HTML code:

```
 <div class="galerie">
   <div><a class="popup" href="path-to-large-image"><img src="path-to-thumb"><p>legend</p></a></div>
   <div><a class="popup" href="path-to-large-image"><img src="path-to-thumb"><p>legend</p></a></div>
   <div><a class="popup" href="path-to-large-image"><img src="path-to-thumb"><p>legend</p></a></div>
 </div>
```

Now I'd like to group these elements into one gallery. I've tried with this JavaScript code:

```
 $('.popup').magnificPopup({
     delegate: 'a',
     type: 'image'
 });
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work.  Can anyone help?

Comment: Code, that you posted is correct. Look for problem on side of including scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
 $('.galerie').magnificPopup({
 delegate: 'a',
 type: 'image'
 });
```

You should call the all gallery not a single image.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone wants to know how to set up groups in magnific popup you need to 
use the 'gallery' option:

```
$('.images').magnificPopup({
    type: 'image',
    gallery{
        enabled: true
    }
});
```

Source: http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#gallery

Comment: You have an error in code!
There must be a colon, after `gallery`, see working example here http://jsfiddle.net/d2fp5o0o/1/